# Why does return to caller work for `List` but not `Map`?

Tags: kotlin

I want to "break" out of `forEach` and return directly to the caller of `bar` on certain conditions.

With `List` this works:

```
fun bar(collection: List<String>): Boolean {
    collection.forEach { value ->
        if ("foo".equals(value))
            return true
    }
    return false
}
```

But if `collection` is a `Map`, I get a compilation error:

```
fun bar(collection: Map<String, String>): Boolean {
    collection.forEach { key, value ->
        if ("foo".equals(key))
            return true // compilation error: 'return' is not allowed here. 
    }
    return false
}
```

Why?

(Please don't mind the use of forEach for simple searching in this case. This is just a minimal sample. The actual code is a lot more complex.)

Comment: please note that nearly anything that can be expressed with `forEach` can also be expressed using other means... and often it results in something simpler at the end... but it may take more time to find the appropriate solution... (but sometimes you then see that you might have chosen the wrong data structure to begin with) ... I just mention that because you say that this is only a minimal sample, but the original is way more complex ;-))

Comment: maybe the following is also interesting for you in that particular case: [Kotlin reference - SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ricky Mo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53531521/4465208) is on the right track about explaining why your error happens, but I think there's more to add about how to solve it.

To recap that answer in short:

- Your current call to `forEach` on a `List` is calling the Kotlin standard library function [`Iterable.forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html), which is an inline function, [thus allowing you to return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) from `bar` within the lambda you pass to it. This function takes a lambda parameter, which itself has just a single parameter.
- In the other case, with a `Map`, you're actually calling a Java [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method defined on `Map` that takes a `BiConsumer`, an interface that's essentially a two-parameter lambda. Java has no concept of inlining, therefore you can't do a non-local return from this `BiConsumer`.

Let's talk solutions.

1. You could use the Kotlin `Iterable.forEach` in the case of a `Map` too, since it *is* an `Iterable`. To call this `forEach`, you just need to pass a lambda that takes a single parameter instead of two:

   ```
   collection.forEach { entry ->
       if ("foo".equals(entry.key))
           return true
   }
   ```

   The return will work here, since *this* `forEach` is inlined.
2. You can make the previous call this way as well, using [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas-since-11) on the map entries:

   ```
   collection.forEach { (key, value) ->
       if ("foo".equals(key))
           return true
   }
   ```

   This syntax is very close to your original call (perhaps annoyingly so), but this lambda still has a single parameter, making this a call to the Kotlin standard library `forEach` function instead of to the Java method, which takes two parameters.
3. As a last minor step, you could use `_` as the name of the value if you don't use it within the lambda:

   ```
   collection.forEach { (key, _) ->
       if ("foo".equals(key))
           return true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`Map` has a different implementation of `forEach`. You can look into the source code.

For `List`:

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

For `Map` (this is java):

```
default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        K k;
        V v;
        try {
            k = entry.getKey();
            v = entry.getValue();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            // this usually means the entry is no longer in the map.
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException(ise);
        }
        action.accept(k, v);
    }
}
```

The `list.forEach` accept a `function type` while `map.forEach` accept a `BiConsumer` instance.

For `List`, as suggested by the `inline` keyword, you can replace the `forEach` call with

```
for (value in collection) 
{
    if("foo".equals(value))
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

and everything make sense with the return.

The lambda you pass to the `map.forEach` is actually the implementation of the member function `accept` of the `BiConsumer` interface, which type is `void`. That's why returning a `Boolean` make no sense. Even you just `return`, it just end the `accept` method. Since this is not a kotlin `inline` function, it won't end the enclosing function.

Java source code of `BiConsumer`

```
public interface BiConsumer<T, U> {

    /**
     * Performs this operation on the given arguments.
     *
     * @param t the first input argument
     * @param u the second input argument
     */
    void accept(T t, U u);

    /**
     * Returns a composed {@code BiConsumer} that performs, in sequence, this
     * operation followed by the {@code after} operation. If performing either
     * operation throws an exception, it is relayed to the caller of the
     * composed operation.  If performing this operation throws an exception,
     * the {@code after} operation will not be performed.
     *
     * @param after the operation to perform after this operation
     * @return a composed {@code BiConsumer} that performs in sequence this
     * operation followed by the {@code after} operation
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code after} is null
     */
    default BiConsumer<T, U> andThen(BiConsumer<? super T, ? super U> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);

        return (l, r) -> {
            accept(l, r);
            after.accept(l, r);
        };
    }
}
```

Without any simplification, your function actually looks like this:

```
fun bar(collection: Map<String, String>): Boolean {
    val action : BiConsumer<String,String> = object : BiConsumer<String, String> {
        override fun accept(t: String, u: String) {
            //return boolean is not allow here
            //return at here just end the accept function. bar is not affected
        }
    }
    collection.forEach(action)
    return false
}
```

Since kotlin converts single method interface implementation to lambda, it gives you an illusion that `map.forEach` looks like an inline call accepting a `function type` just like `List`. The truth is that the lambda accepted by `map.forEach` is not a kotlin `function type` but a `BiConsumer` implementation instead, and most importantly, it is not `inline`.